# finding a class within the same div with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to find a `class` corresponding to another `class` within the same `div`.

**HTML structure:**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="party">
                <a href="#"><img id="1001" class="vote" src="http://img2.jpg"></a>
                <p class="votenums"> 20 votes.</p>
  </div>

   <div class="party">
                <a href="#"><img id="1001" class="vote" src="http://imgtwo2.jpg"></a>
                <p class="votenums"> 30 votes.</p>
  </div>
```

**jQuery code is:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".vote").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find(".votenums").text("changed text");
    });
});
```

When I click img with class `vote` I want to edit the class `votenums`, corresponding to the same div. 
meaning, the desired behavior is, when the image is clicked the text should change.

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/85vMX/1/

Comment: Your's fiddle uses **mootools** not **jquery**...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`find` searches down, and `.votenums` isn't a descendant of `.vote` you should traverse up to the `div` and then find the descendant `.votenums`

```
$(function() {
    $(".vote").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').find(".votenums").text("changed text");
    });
});
```

If the div you want will always has `class=party` you can search by it:
`$(this).closest('.party').find(".votenums").text("changed text");`
*Class selector is better than element selector*

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/85vMX/4/)

**find:**

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

**closest:**

> Description: Get the first element that matches the selector,
>   beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM
>   tree.

Comment: @user902620. class selector is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and robust approach is to go back up to `.party` using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then come back down using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(".vote").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.party').find('.votenums').text("changed text");
});
```

That lets you change the internal arrangement of `.party` without breaking your jQuery.

Comment: @user902620. you used **mootools** and **not jquery**. see my JSFiddle.

Comment: @user902620: It works fine if when the fiddle uses jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/85vMX/5/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason to set the `class` and `ID` to the `img` element, my suggestion would be to go for a tidier `html` code. After all, it doesn't make sense to apply `.preventDefault()` on the `img` tag since not event is expected, in that case this is what the `<a>` tag is used for so:

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="party">
  <a id="1001" class="vote" href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_XeuZ1yDnv4Q/TSUkAT6T1dI/AAAAAAAADR8/nPHP4JvVxy8/s1600/vote.jpg"></a>
  <p class="votenums"> 20 votes.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="party">
  <a id="1002" class="vote" href="#"><img src="http://bgathinktank.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/vote-button.jpg"></a>
  <p class="votenums"> 30 votes.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I set a different `ID` for each link above since it's not a good idea to use the same `ID` for two different elements within the same document. `IDs` should be unique.

Then your best move would be to upgrade to jQuery v1.7.x (if you haven't yet) and use jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live()`. You will find this on the jQuery site:

*As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.* ... there is also [a good article to read here](http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live)

Then you could use a less costly function like

```
$(function() {
 $(".vote").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).next('.votenums').text("changed text");
 });
});
```

And last, the css would need a little tweak too

```
.vote img{
    height:70px;
    width:70px;   
}
```